# Windows 7 Installation booting goes black

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub

Windows 7 Installation goes black and blank when trying to boot it.

This started happening after I installed Linux and GRUB. GRUB shows Windows 7 and Linux as options, but Windows 7 needs the installation CD to repair  booting after the error:

`0xc0000098 - The Windows Boot Configuration Data file does not contain a valid OS entry`

However, when I try to boot it the screen goes black and freezes, not booting or doing anything. So I have to eject the CD, and restart the computer manually so I can use Linux.

Answer (score 0):

First repair Windows 7 boot using Windows repair/installation DVD/USB - select Repair - "Automatic Repair".

Then [reinstall GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) using Linux CD/DVD/USB.

Consider an alternative way of [dual-booting Linux and Windows](https://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) using Windows boot manager (works only for MBR style disks and BIOS boot).